# SparkLauncher wont open a second spark process

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I wrote a Spark app that listens to a kafka topic.

The recived messages contain a topic name and a parquet path and whenever a message arrives the app opens a new Spark process that listens to the Kafka topic that was recieved and writes the incoming data to the parquet path that was recieved.

I tried in my local PC and managed to open several process that listen to different topics.

When I ran the JAR on the cloud, the first process opened and worked as expected, but when I tried to open a second process, it did not open.

This is how I opened the spark process:

```
val spark = new SparkLauncher()
                  .setAppResource(jarPath)
                  .setMainClass("Namespace.ClassName")
                  .setAppName("Name"+topicName)
                  .AddAppArgs(topicName, parquetName)
                  .StartApplication();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a cluster to test it on at the moment but maybe... use:

```
.setMaster
```

and

```
.setDeployMode
```